# Unite two last items in the end of list, without commas (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

*This code splits a string every two items, separated by commas and if the quantity of all items is odd items it need to add "*" symbol to the last (odd) item in the list.

```
def split_string(string: str) -> list:

    result = []
    for char in range(0, len(string), 2):
        result.append(string[char: char + 2])

    if len(string) % 2 != 0:
         result.append("_") 
        
    return result


split_string("abcde")
```

Code returns ["ab", "cd", "e", "*"] but I need ["ab", "cd", "e*"], i.e. "e_"  without a comma between the last two items "e" and "*". So I need code to return ["ab", "cd", "e*"] i.e underscore after "e" without space and comma as a symbol of an absent second item. Please help to get the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code returns `["ab", "cd", "e", "_"]`, not `["ab", "cd", "e", ""]`. You should use `result[-1] += "_"` in the if statement. Your current code appends to the list, while `result[-1]` appends to the last element of the list (you can not use `append()` on strings, hence the `+=` concatenation operator).

I recommend changing the condition in the if statement as well, this would be easier to understand later: `if len(result[-1]) != 2:`.

Comment: I need code to return ["ab","cd", "e_"] i.e underscore as a symbol of absent second item

Comment: yes,  result[-1] += "_" does the job, thanks a lot!